# How to adjust div of row2 below the row1 like in picture

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap and in my first row i have 2 side one contain picture and other div but image size is larger the left side div so my 2nd row div come after picture. but my requirement is make 2nd row div just below the first row div?  [Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7m4B.png)

Comment: share your html and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container"> // Container for two side contents
 <div class ="row"> // single row
     <div class ="Row1"> 
        // Your's Row1 code goes here
     </div>
     <div class="Row2">
       // Your's Row2 code goes here
     </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container"> // Container for main contents(gallery and big image)
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate the blocks like:

```
<div class="overall-container">
   <div class="left-block" style="width: 30%;">
      // add your navigation blocks here
   </div>
   <div class="right-block" style="width: 70%;">
      //add page content here
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be responsive if we fix it width?

Comment: the width isn't fixed its based on a percentage which you can always change with CSS media quieries

Answer (score -1):

Make Another Row in yours first row.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
</div>
</div>
```